# How to find exact matching values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I find the exact match in case of duplicate values in SQL
I am using the below query to find customers which are having write access based on the below values.

```
user **A write** user - {UI.ACCESS, API.ACCESS} and
user **B read** user - {UI.ACCESS, API.ACCESS, UI.READONLY, API.READONLY}
```

Query -

```
select  ul.USERNAME,sp.PERMISSION_N,cus.ID 
from CUSTOMER cus 
    join USER_L ul on cus.ID = ul.CUSTOMER_ID 
    join USER_ROLE ur on ul.ID = ur.USER_ID 
    join SECURITY_ROLE sr on ur.SECURITY_ROLE_ID = sr.SECURITY_ROLE_ID 
    join SECURITY_PERMISSION sp on sr.SECURITY_PERMISSION_ID = sp.ID 
where sp.PERMISSION_NAME in ('UI.ACCESS','API.ACCESS')
```

above query return the B user as well but I am expecting only A.

Comment: Oracle and MySQL are different RDBMS. Which one are you using? Also, please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check across all the rows in the `SECURITY_PERMISSION` table that none of them have the forbidden roles.

You have tagged both Oracle and MySQL. In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
SELECT ul.USERNAME,
       sp.permission_names,
       cus.ID 
FROM   CUSTOMER cus 
       INNER JOIN USER_L ul
       ON (cus.ID = ul.CUSTOMER_ID)
       INNER JOIN USER_ROLE ur
       ON (ul.ID = ur.USER_ID)
       INNER JOIN SECURITY_ROLE sr
       ON (ur.SECURITY_ROLE_ID = sr.SECURITY_ROLE_ID)
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                LISTAGG(permission_name, ',')
                  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY permission_name)
                  AS permission_names
         FROM   SECURITY_PERMISSION
         GROUP BY id
         HAVING COUNT(
                  CASE
                  WHEN PERMISSION_NAME in ('UI.ACCESS','API.ACCESS')
                  THEN 1
                  END
                ) > 0
         AND    COUNT(
                  CASE
                  WHEN PERMISSION_NAME in ('UI.READONLY', 'API.READONLY')
                  THEN 1
                  END
                ) = 0
       ) sp
       ON (sr.SECURITY_PERMISSION_ID = sp.ID)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE customer (id) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;

CREATE TABLE user_l (id, customer_id, username) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL, 'User' || LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;

CREATE TABLE user_role (id, user_id, security_role_id) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;

CREATE TABLE security_role (security_role_id, security_permission_id) AS
SELECT LEVEL, LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2;

CREATE TABLE security_permission (id, permission_name) AS
SELECT 1, 'UI.ACCESS'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'API.ACCESS'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'UI.ACCESS'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'API.ACCESS'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'UI.READONLY'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'API.READONLY' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | USERNAME | PERMISSION_NAMES | ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | User1 | API.ACCESS,UI.ACCESS | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5766c78b98406ce8dbd0b92866f31b80)*

---

For MySQL, you would need to replace `LISTAGG` with something to aggregate strings such as `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: ON (sr.SECURITY_PERMISSION_ID = sp.ID)  the last line shows error because sp.ID is not accessible outside the INNER JOIN bracket. I am using oracle. Thanks for the approach.

Comment: @user10089165 Updated to move the `sp` alias outside the brackets around the sub-query.

Comment: this is still returning the READ user as well.

Comment: @user10089165 Updated with a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5766c78b98406ce8dbd0b92866f31b80) that shows it working. If it does not work for you then you need to look at what is different in your table structures and/or data and [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71309157/edit) your question to include a [MRE] because without more details we cannot tell why you are not getting the expected output and making statements that are effectively equivalent to "its not working" is not constructive as it does not tell us why it is not working.